# how to do a login greeting (toast) and don't have to type again when user log in

Tags: android

I would like to make a userlogin details, using shared preferences.

when I load the application a login page will appear. After I've typed in , it will toast a greeting to the user, such as welcome [username]. When the user login again, it will toast a message welcome back [username]. The user do not have to type his/her name again to go in the application. In fact, when the user click login, it will toast welcome back [username], and he/she can continue with the application.

However, in my code, it just skip the login page , and didn't toast the name.
I did a log.d but nothing appear in my logcat.
Can someone please help me out?

I think there's something not right with my retrieve preference, but I am not sure how can I edit it, I'm new to android.

here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.login);

     username =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
     loginbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBTN);
     loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
          Bundle extras = new Bundle();
          extras.putString("name",username.getText().toString());
          intent.putExtras(extras);
          startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);
     }
            });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    saveAsPreferences();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    retrievePreferences();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}

public void saveAsPreferences() {
    String name = username.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString("name", name);

    editor.commit();

}// saveAsPreferences

public void retrievePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (prefs.contains("name")) {
        String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
        Log.d("Login","name : "+name);
        username.setText(name);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome" + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homeActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);        
    }
          else
          {

                if (prefs.contains("name")) {
                    String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
                    Log.d("ELSE","name : "+name);
                    username.setText(name);
          }

    }

    }
}
```

hom.java

```
public class homeActivity extends Activity{
    Button btnLogIn;
    Button btnAbout;
    TextView name;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
         name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);        
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(extras != null)
         {
             String username = extras.getString("name");
             name.setText(username);
         }
```

Comment: why are you starting the activity twice?

Comment: I wanted to pass it into another activity, so that if I have the username in the database, I wouldn't have to ask the user to enter his/her name again. instead it will just toast "welcome back [user]" I just updated my code

Answer (score 0):

I looked to your code.Why you start your Home activity twice in `onClickListener` ?

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homeActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putString("name",username.getText().toString());
 intent.putExtras(extras);
 startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);
```

You had started it with `startActivity(intent);` and then with `startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);`.I guess that causes the problem.

Comment: yeah.. and its wrong also that he retrieves the name in `onResume` and save the prefs in `onPause`.

Comment: I remove one of the intent, I'm able to get the log now, however ,it's not the outcome that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

i think you closed the app from a different activity, so when you re-launced..it launced the last activity you were in